# Moviepy textclip with pango method not working

Tags: python, moviepy, pango

I am using Moviepy to write text on videoclip. Without `method=pango` it gives proper results
[image]

But when I use `method=pango` it does not show the text and shows some unrecognizable characters
[image]

My textclip without pango looks like this:

```
(
TextClip(text_line.strip().upper(), font="URW-Bookman-Demi", fontsize=100, color='yellow')
                    .set_position(('center', 'center'))
                    .set_duration(end-start)
                    .set_start(start)
                   )
)
```

My textclip with pango looks like this:

```
(
TextClip(f'{text_line}<span foreground="#FF4567" background="black"><tt>{key}</tt></span>', 
           font="DejaVu Mono Sans", fontsize=100, color='yellow', method="pango")
           .set_position(('center', 'center'))
           .set_duration(end-start)
           .set_start(start)
)
```

I want to have only a particular word colored, `{key}` contains that word and `{text_line}` is remaining sentence.

I'm running this in colab.
Am I missing some dependencies?
I'm installing following:

```
!apt update
!apt install -y libpango-1.0-0
!apt install -y libsdl-pango-dev
!apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-4.0
!apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev gir1.2-gtk-4.0
!apt install imagemagick
!apt install ffmpeg
!pip3 install moviepy
!sed -i '/<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@\*"/d' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
!pip install imageio
!pip install --upgrade imageio-ffmpeg
!pip install pycairo
!pip install PyGObject
```

Or is it the font? Or something else?

Comment: Changed the font to  'Arial' and it worked. Now need to find which fonts are supported, if  anyone can help with that it would be great.

Comment: looks like unicode text problem. if reading text from file  pass encoding parameter 

encoding="utf8"